# Close modal popup in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I have an image that will display a modal once clicked. If I click outside of the modal window it closes just fine, however if I click on the `X`, which I've put in a `span` tag, it's not closing. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal1");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn1" class="button2"><img class="box" src="image.png"></button>
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Some text in the Modal..</h2>
    More text in modal...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code in your question works fine. I can only presume that there's more than one `.close` element in your actual HTML page, and the one related to the modal is not the first one. Also note that I retagged the question as this has nothing to do with jQuery. It's pure JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It did not really work as expected. See my answer for a complete version

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example of what you are looking for

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal1");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
var close = document.querySelector("#myModal1 .close");



// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
btn.addEventListener("click",function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}) 
close.addEventListener("click",function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}) 
window.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const inside = modal.contains(e.target);
  if (!inside && e.target !== btn) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

```css
.modal { display:none }
```

```html
<button id="myBtn1" class="button2">Click</button>
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Some text in the Modal..</h2>
    More text in modal...
  </div>
</div>
```